# ansible playbook not running properly

Tags: ansible

Below is my ansible playbook

```
---
- name: Schema Backup Script
  hosts: hosts1:hosts2:hosts3
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:

  - name: Copy the script to Managed node
    copy:
     src: backup.sh
     dest: ~/
     mode: 0777
    become: true
    become_user: user1

  - name: Execute the Export command
    shell: sh ~/backup.sh
    become: true
    become_user: user1

  - name: Delete the script copied on Managed node
    file:
     path: ~/backup.sh
     state: absent
    become: true
    become_user: user1
...
```

The problem when i run this playbook task 2 i.e Execute the Export command is executing but task 1 is not executing.

Comment: Could you paste the error please?

Comment: @bosari Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password,hostbased) i have crossed my file permission everything is good

Comment: Which host are you trying to copy the backup.sh file ? Is it a remote server or the same from where you are executing this playbook ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [script module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) when you want to execute a local script on remote nodes

2) You can not use `~` in Ansible modules parameters because it is a shell feature